# Where does the new electron come (beta particle) from in beta decay?

Tags: electrons, nuclear-physics, radioactivity

In beta decay neutrons convert into proton, in that process they'll release an electron (called beta particle) but mass still remains same 
$$_zX^A \longrightarrow\;  _{z+1}Y^{A}+ e^- $$
The question is where did that beta particle came out from no where like matter can't be created or destroyed? 
Or am I misinterpreting something?

Comment: Matter *can* be created and destroyed - that's what radioactivity *is*.

Comment: It should be noted that the neutron is more massive than the proton, so nucleus X is more massive than nucleus Y, though this difference is very small.

Comment: E=mc^2, so energy can be converted to mass (and vice versa)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [beta decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay) a neutron decays into a proton, an electron and an antineutrino. More precisely, one of the down quarks within the neutron changes into an up quark and emits a short-lived $W^-$ boson, which quickly decays into an electron and an antineutrino. The change of flavour by the quark turns the neutron into a proton.

The electron and the antineutrino do not have to "come" from anywhere. Transformations of one fundamental particle into another (or a set of others) can happen provided certain conservation conditions are met. In the case of beta decay we have

- Conservation of charge - the charge of the neutron is $0$ and the net charge of the proton, the electron and the (uncharged) neutrino is $0$.
- Conservation of energy - the neutron is more massive than the decay products, but the mass difference is accounted for by the kinetic energy of the  decay products.
- Conservation of momentum
- Conservation of baryon number/quark number - the transformation leaves the number of quarks minus the number of antiquarks unchanged.
- Conservation of lepton number - the lepton number of the neutron and the proton are $0$. The lepton number of the electron is $+1$, but this is balanced by the lepton number of the antineutrino, which is $-1$.

Comment: "*Conservation of boson number - ...*"
You probably mean conservation of *quark* number (quarks are not bosons).

Comment: @ThomasFritsch Yes indeed - fixed.

Comment: "the proton is more massive than the decay products" ... did you mean "neutron" instead of "proton"?

Comment: @Michael Yes I did. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks, @ThomasFritsch. The OP probably meant [baryon number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon_number).

Comment: i forgot to ask another thing but do we need to supply some energy in order to start decay process? something similiar to activation energy? since a neutral atom has number of protons $=$ no of electrons, why would it want to decay in first place as everything is balanced?

Comment: @Rambalheartremo No, we do not have to provide energy - beta decay can be spontaneous if a nucleus is unstable (which has nothing to do with ionisation state or orbital electrons). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay for more information.